# Id with RadioButtonFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I'm trying to deal with radiobutton ids in asp MVC 5

I'm working like this

Example model

```
class A
{
   public bool? radio { get; set; }
}
```

and in razor view

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NeutroBT, Model.NeutroBT, new { @id = "True"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NeutroBT, !Model.NeutroBT, new { @id = "False})
```

It doesn't cause problem, but I'm working in an editortemplate, and I want it to have generated `id`, to access in some way like `@Html.IdFor(x => x.NeutroBT, true)` and `@Html.IdFor(x => x.NeutroBT, false)` from the other views, just preventing changes in the future

Is some like this possible? I pass a lot of time searching and I didn't get anything similar

If is not possible, what is the best way to deal with it?

thanks!

Comment: Why have an `id` at all? (and as a side note, its `@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NeutroBT, true, new { ... })` (not `(bool)Model.NeutroBT`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi, thanks for response, i changed a bit the code, i pass the model as second parameter to get true or false, i want to have an id to access it from javascript, what do you recommend me? access them by name?

Comment: No. You use `true` and `false` as the 2nd parameter. And why would you need to access it it javascript by id? - you can access it by `name`

Comment: i really dont think about that, i will access them with name, a little question about it, it would cause problems if i dont override the id and both use the same id?

Comment: You use `new { id = "" }` so that the attribute is removed

Comment: Thanks so much, if you can, answer the question, so I can label it as correct!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178855/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-juan-salvador-portugal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use an `id` attribute. Instead you can just use the `name` attribute to select or set the value via javascript (and in any case, `@Html.IdFor() will only ever return`NeutroBT`, not the`id`that you override in the`RadioButtonFor()` method so it cannot be used in your case)

In addition, the 2nd parameter of `RadioButtonFor()` should be `true` or `false` (not `Model.NeutroBT` and `!Model.NeutroBT`).

And to associate a label with the button, you can wrap it in a `<label>`, for example

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NeutroBT, true, new { id = ""})
    <span>Yes</span>
</label>
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.NeutroBT, false, new { id = ""})
    <span>No</span>
</label>
```

Note that `new { id = "" }` removes the `id` attribute and prevents invalid html due to duplicate `id` attributes.

Then to access the selected value using jQuery

```
var selectedValue = $('input[name="' + @Html.NameFor(x => x.NeutroBT) + '"]:checked').val();
```